# Alchemy GetNFTsForOwner mint address is null

Tags: solidity, blockchain, nft, polygon, alchemy

I'm using GetNFTsForOwner from Alchemy SDK and I expected to get minting information such as mintAddress and transactionHash to linked to my data on my database. But in my result the mint data is null. Can someone explain why this happened? or is alchemy doesn't store the mint data in their server? Or do I need to do something in the smart contract.

```
{ "ownedNfts": [{
  "contract": {
    "address": "0x40d86e4598eD2061BEf14Df09C80beC047447EE2",
    "name": "Foodygo NFT",
    "symbol": null,
    "totalSupply": "3",
    "tokenType": "ERC1155",
    "contractDeployer": null,
    "deployedBlockNumber": null,
    "openSeaMetadata": {
      "floorPrice": null,
      "collectionName": null,
      "collectionSlug": null,
      "safelistRequestStatus": null,
      "imageUrl": null,
      "description": null,
      "externalUrl": null,
      "twitterUsername": null,
      "discordUrl": null,
      "bannerImageUrl": null,
      "lastIngestedAt": "2024-01-11T09:27:16.000Z"
    },
    "isSpam": null,
    "spamClassifications": []
  },
  "tokenId": "1",
  "tokenType": "ERC1155",
  "name": "meats",
  "description": null,
  "tokenUri": "https://bafybeibxakd4arpgjaigz77d4umk2qzew4bld55ikqzkvngaq3gdhxtr6u.ipfs.nftstorage.link/ingredient-1.json",
  "image": {
    "cachedUrl": "https://nft-cdn.alchemy.com/matic-mumbai/26a569cb4a24910f9d2581b0be01cd76",
    "thumbnailUrl": null,
    "pngUrl": "https://res.cloudinary.com/alchemyapi/image/upload/convert-png/matic-mumbai/26a569cb4a24910f9d2581b0be01cd76",
    "contentType": "image/png",
    "size": null,
    "originalUrl": "https://ipfs.io/ipfs/bafybeiczyd735zx3hqqvat6gnzdvc5qpjkux2mezd6ipsmuc2okjfdsbx4/1-meats.png"
  },
  "raw": {
    "tokenUri": "https://bafybeibxakd4arpgjaigz77d4umk2qzew4bld55ikqzkvngaq3gdhxtr6u.ipfs.nftstorage.link/ingredient-1.json",
    "metadata": {
      "name": "meats",
      "image": "https://bafybeiczyd735zx3hqqvat6gnzdvc5qpjkux2mezd6ipsmuc2okjfdsbx4.ipfs.nftstorage.link/ipfs/bafybeiczyd735zx3hqqvat6gnzdvc5qpjkux2mezd6ipsmuc2okjfdsbx4/1-meats.png",
      "nft_type": "ingredient"
    },
    "error": null
  },
  "collection": null,
  "mint": {
    "mintAddress": null,
    "blockNumber": null,
    "timestamp": null,
    "transactionHash": null
  },
  "owners": null,
  "timeLastUpdated": "2024-01-16T09:02:53.152Z",
  "balance": "1",
  "acquiredAt": {
    "blockTimestamp": null,
    "blockNumber": null
  }
}]}
```